Transpose of the matrix not work properlly
I am writing code for transpose of matrix but it not work proper
def Transpose(matrix_org,matrix_tran):
for i in range(len(matrix_org)):
    for j in range(len(matrix_org[0])):
        matrix_tran[i][j]=matrix_org[j][i]
return matrix_tran 


While your post lacks issue details, instead of fixing it why don't you use existing solutions such as NumPy's transpose?

Just change below line
matrix_tran[j][i] = matrix_org[i][j]

The full code will be
def Transpose(matrix_org):
      # Initialize the transposed matrix with swapped dimensions
      matrix_tran = [[0 for _ in range(len(matrix_org))] for _ in range(len(matrix_org[0]))]

      # Transpose the matrix
      for i in range(len(matrix_org)):
           for j in range(len(matrix_org[0])):
               matrix_tran[j][i] = matrix_org[i][j]

      return matrix_tran

  # Example usage
  matrix_org = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]
  ]

  transposed_matrix = Transpose(matrix_org)
  for row in transposed_matrix:
      print(row)

